unity3d Calculate Accuracy of 2 colliders hitting
I'm using unity3d 2022.3.10f and I am trying to work out how accurate someone hits an object with the controller in a VR game I am doing for the oculus.
To simplify this so I can test repeatedly with various scenarios, I have a static object (sphere) that has a collider on it. I have a 2nd object (another sphere) that also has a collider on it.
They are directly inline with each other e.g.
Sphere 1: is at 0,1,1
Sphere 2: is at 0,1,0
So they are 1 distance on the z axis.
I then impart a velocity to sphere 2 to send it exactly towards Sphere 1 (0,0,1). When the colliders trigger - I want a % rating of how accurate they collided - basically projecting the center of sphere 2 on its path to see how close it would have come to hitting the center of sphere 1.
In my above example I would expect a % of 100% as they were on exact collision course.
If I then change the velocity imparted on Sphere 2 to make it still collide but very slightly offline i.e. velocity of (0,0.04,1) - I would expect a lower % value e.g. 75% and so on to a % of near 0 if they just about scrape when then hit.
I have tried many different ways but unable to come up with anything.
Has anyone got code to do this they could share?
Thank you for your time.
R
EDIT: The 2 sphere scenario is just for testing as a rig so I can accurately change slightly the angles/speed etc to see how the percentage hit calcs are working.
I do have a script attached to each hand controller that gives me the Average Velocity (int) and Average Direction (Vector3) for each controller all the time i.e. it is stored currently in a singleton value for each controller and updated per frame so I can easily access it.
So if this can be used to calculate the accuracy of the collider hit maybe?
Here is the Velocity and Direction script:
public class AverageDirectionCalculator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3[] recentPositions = new Vector3[10];
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        // Store the current position in the array
        recentPositions[currentIndex] = transform.position;

        // Increment the index and wrap around if necessary
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % recentPositions.Length;
    }

    public Vector3 GetAverageDirection()
    {
        Vector3 averageDirection = Vector3.zero;

        // Calculate the average direction based on the stored positions
        for (int i = 0; i < recentPositions.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            averageDirection += (recentPositions[i + 1] - recentPositions[i]).normalized;
        }

        // Normalize the result to get the average direction
        averageDirection.Normalize();

        return averageDirection;
    }

    public int GetVelocity()
    {
        // Calculate the velocity based on the magnitude of the most recent position change
        int previousIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + recentPositions.Length) % recentPositions.Length;
        float velocity = (recentPositions[currentIndex] - recentPositions[previousIndex]).magnitude / Time.deltaTime;

        float maxPossibleVelocity = 100f;
        float scaledVelocity = (velocity / maxPossibleVelocity) * 100f;

        // Cast the scaled velocity to an integer
        int scaledVelocityInt = Mathf.RoundToInt(scaledVelocity);

        return scaledVelocityInt;
    }
}

EDIT: ANSWER
I think I have worked out a workable solution with the help of derHugo help and advice.
Step 1: I get the Vector3 of the controller from my AverageDirection script at the point of impact so I know the rough trajectory the controller was moving in on impact
Step 2: I work out a step movement - in my case 1/250'th of the Vector3 - this will give me a slice to move along the trajectory
Step 3: Loop - move along the trajectory path in increments of the step (1/250th) and calculate the distance from the new Vector3 to the target position
Step 4: Keep doing this until I find the smallest distance
This then gives me how close along that trajectory the controller would have hit the target.
Seems to work. Below is the process (in test form):
Note: I add a sphere to each step just to visualise the trajectory was indeed on the correct path - just for testing.
 float _distanceToTarget = 0f;
 float _minDistanceFound = 1000f;
 Vector3 _stepAmount = Vector3.zero;
 Vector3 _refPoint = Vector3.zero;


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{    


 _distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(collider.transform.position, transform.position);
    _minDistanceFound = _distanceToTarget;
    _stepAmount = controllerDirection / StepDiv;
    _refPoint = transform.position;



var target = collider.transform.position;

while (_distanceToTarget <= _minDistanceFound)
{
    _refPoint = _refPoint + _stepAmount;
    _distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(target, _refPoint);
    if (_distanceToTarget < _minDistanceFound)
    {
        _minDistanceFound = _distanceToTarget;
    }

GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
sphere.transform.position = _refPoint;
sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.06f, 0.06f, 0.06f);


}

}

There is bound to be a math way of doing this rather than small step slices moving forward, but I don't know how so this seems to workout.
Thank you hope this helps someone else if needed.

You could probably use angles for that.
If your sphere is at a certain distance and has a certain radius and your projectile also has a projectileRadius you can basically calculate a range of angle around the direction
Shoot origin -> target center

within which you will just miss the target.
This you can basically do using a right scalene triangle math like e.g.
// distance between shoot origin and target center
// = adjacent of the triangle
var distance = Vector3.Distance(shootOrigin.position, target.position);
// maximum distance between projectile and target so you just miss it - just sum both radius
// = opposite of the triangle
var maxDistance = projectileRadius + targetRadius;
// maximum angle using arcsin
// = angle of the triangle
var maxAngle = Mathf.Asin(maxDistance / distance) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

So you can simply check the angle between
// the actual angle between the two directions when hitting the target
var hitAngle = Vector3.Angle(target.position - shootOrigin.position, projectile.position - shootOrigin.position);

And now all that's left is basically mapping this angle onto the percentage using the before calculated maxAngle
// clamp the derail to maximum 1 so accuracy will be directly inverted 
// 0 miss, 1 full hit
var accuracy = 1f - Mathf.Min(hitAngle / maxAngle, 1f);


Thank you so much for the reply.
Calculating the hitAngle bit of code - i don't have 3 objects i.e. I don't have shootOrigin.
I have 1 sphere that is stationary (the target) and another sphere (let's call it the projectile) - the projectile is moving towards the target but it doesn't have a "shootorigin" - the reason being in "real life" this will be the hand controller moving through space towards the target.
So I only have 2 points of reference - the target and the projectile (hand controller) - when they trigger the collider hit.
Hope this makese sense?

You still have three points .. at some point you start shooting the projectile.. so in that moment you can already calculate your triangle .. it is of course a simplification and not 100% accurate, and assumes the projectile moves in a straight line ... but yes you do have the point where your sphere starts moving, the target and the final hit point which are your 3 points .. you just have to store the position where your sphere started moving - or even precalculate the entire thing beforehand using a Physics.SphereCast

Thank you for the reply. The 2 spheres moving are just a rig scenario I am using to test these calculations. In the real game the one sphere is the users hand controller i.e. it is constantly moving around in 3d world and not "firing" from a point. The end result I am looking for in VR on the oculus is to calculate how accurately the users hand controller hit the target - so there is no actual projectile - just my rig has it that way so I can repeat the tests altering the angles slightly.

I have edited the main question to include some more info regarding Velocity and Direction scripts/values - this might help in the calculations.
I do appreciate your replies and knowledge on this and sorry if my example/setup rig or explanation is a bit confusing.

If I understand correctly I think you still have enough information to use above calculation -- you get targetPosition, targetRadius, handPositionDuringHit, handDirectionDuringHit -> can calclate (or just use)previousHandPosition (<- this is basically the shoot origin in above snippets) in order to avoid math issues with the approximation of the angle you can basically extrapolate the move direction and simply assume your hand started moving in a linear direction from further away

In general now seeing more of your code: In GetAverageDirection you have to correctly wrap around and begin at the current index

Thanks again for helping.
Yes that's kind of what I was wondering - if I have the approx hand direction at the point of contact, I would extrapolate the hand backwards as you say and then use your formula. I have no idea how to extrapolate backwards tho? any ideas? or how far to move back? So kind of you helping me out.
(Your text wrapping around a curved surface - I will be using that soon too as I need something exactly like that too hehe). You star.

I think you would have to experiment a bit with the distance ... you basically simply invert the last known average direction and multiply it by some factor - that factor should be big enough (it should be at least bigger than the two radius of course) and also small enough to still allow you to map your range on it - the main inaccuracy of my above approximation happens if the distance is too small => I am simply assuming a right scalene triangle but actually you would have to calculate with positions on a circle arc - in other words just make the distance reasonable big ;)
